# Vectorizing for-loops with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Function in question is `rs`, and the `groups` and `difference` functions that are used in `rs`:

```
def groups(I, mask):
    grp=[]
    m, n = I.shape 
    x, y = np.abs(mask).shape
    for i in range(m-x):
        for j in range(n-y):
            grp.append(I[i:(i+x), j:(j+y)])
    return grp
# }}}

# {{{ difference()
def difference(I, mask):
    cmask = - mask
    cmask[(mask > 0)] = 0
    L = []
    for g in groups(I, mask):
        flip = (g + cmask) ^ np.abs(mask) - cmask
        L.append(np.sign(smoothness(flip) - smoothness(g)))
    N = len(L)
    R = float(L.count(1))/N
    S = float(L.count(-1))/N
    return R-S
# }}}

# {{{ rs()
def rs(filename, channel=0):
    I = imread(filename)
    if channel!=None:
        I = I[:,:,channel]
    I = I.astype(int)

    mask = np.array( [[1,0],[0,1]] )
    d0 = difference(I, mask)
    d1 = difference(I^1, mask)

    mask = -mask
    n_d0 = difference(I, mask)
    n_d1 = difference(I^1, mask)

    p0, p1 = solve(2*(d1+d0), (n_d0-n_d1-d1-3*d0), (d0-n_d0)) 
    if np.abs(p0) < np.abs(p1): 
        z = p0
    else: 
        z = p1

    return z / (z-0.5)
# }}}
```

If you need to see more code, it's at: https://github.com/daniellerch/aletheia/blob/master/aletheialib/attacks.py

As you can see, there are many for-loops within each. `rs` takes minutes to complete. `spa` used to take just as long, but a contributor sped it up using vectorization (and now `spa` takes a few seconds to complete).

I only know a bit about vectorization from working through machine learning tutorials. I've never put it into practice. Can anyone help on this front? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more explanation of what this code is supposed to do; what the various array sizes/shapes are; and what the function `solve` is supposed to do? Consider creating a mimimal verifiable example that can run by itself and demonstrates the problem.